# Why don't neighborhoods need to be connected?

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to wrap my head around the definition for a neighborhood in topology.

A neighborhood of a point $p$ is any subset $s$ of $(S, T)$ that contains an open set containing $p$.

For example, using $\Bbb{R}$ as an example, a neighborhood of $0$ might be $(-1, 1) \cup \{20\}$ using the Euclidean metric/ topology. Intuitively, $20$ has nothing to do with $(-1, 1)$, so why is useful to define a structure that suggests they're somehow connected?

I guess, it seems very unmotivated to say that a neighborhood for a point $p$ can contain disconnected/ far away elements of $S$ distant from $p$ that have no relationship at all to $p$'s open sets.

Comment: Just imagine how complicated it would be to define a neighborhood as "a connected set containing an open set containing $x$". For instance, to prove a function $f$ is continuous at a point $x$, one would need to show that for any connected neighborhood $f(x)\in U$ there is a connected open set in $f^{-1}(U)$ containing  $x$. This would add an unnecessary step to every pretty much any proof involving neighborhoods, for no good reason.

Comment: The {20} is irrelevant.  But it's not useful to tie ourselves in knots to *exclude* it.  It hurts nothing.  The important thing is that it has an open set.  Anything else... who cares.  we could (and some do) require a neighborhood itself to be open.  Connectedness is to high a requirement.  I think it is hypothetically possible to define a topology that's completely disconnected yet with open sets.  The open sets containing points are what's important.  Not connectednes.  Although, to be honest, I'm not sure why neighborhoods being requited to be open isn't part of the definition.

Comment: Not all spaces are locally connected. It might be that some point has no connected neighborhood at all. Take the topologists' sine curve for an example.

Answer (score 0):

What makes point set topology unique is the consideration of "spaces" very different than the Euclidean topology we're used to. It's not just neighborhoods that can be disconnected but open sets can be disconnected too. For example the set of all integers is open in the discrete topology on $\Bbb R$ where every point is defined to be an open set.